# Output Logstash to Elasticsearch cluster

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch

I have multiple EC2 instances running Logstash and Elasticsearch.

I'd like to output everything into ES cluster.

```
output {
        stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json" }
        elasticsearch {
                cluster => "elasticsearch"
        }
}
```

No data is sent to the cluster. I also tried to add bind_host that point to 127.0.0.1 where I have a locally installed Elasticsearch installed. Nothing.

Only option that seems to works is "host". But if the local instance of ES crash, I lost my logs.

How do I output it to a cluster, so it figures out by itself who is the master ?

Comment: You may have to open port 9300 on the AWS security group.

Comment: 9200 and 9300 is opened on all instance.

Comment: The aws-cloud plugin from ES has to be installed in logstash too. I'm still looking how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990344/logstash-output-to-elasticsearch-on-aws-ec2